# What does the Message "relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact is deprecated" mean?

Tags: gradle

my gradle build outputs the message

```
Deprecated: relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact is deprecated, and will not be supported in a future version of Gradle.
```

What does this mean and how to make the warning go away?

Comment: What artifacts does your build produce, and how are they defined?

Comment: If your context is Android development, with the Android Gradle plugin, see this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496956/gradle-deprecation-relying-on-packaging-to-define-the-extension-of-the-main-art

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is saying you depend on some artefact of a type that it does not know about but that it can find by using the "packaging" attribute of the pom. There are enhancements planned here and they are described [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/design-docs/dependency-management-bug-fixes.md#correct-handling-of-packaging-and-dependency-type-declared-in-poms).

Comment: This answer could be enhanced by suggesting how to fix the actual warning. The linked resource doesn't help explain how to make the warning go away.

Comment: to do that, I'd be answering a question that wasn't asked and would need more information from the OP anyway (the specifics of what that dependency is & how it is declared) hence IMV a downvote seems rather harsh

Comment: How to solve this issue is discussed there: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/jhuxhorn_googlemail_com-zal6c

For now, no solution, the warning is said to be 'bugged'.

Answer (score 6):

How to solve this issue is discussed there:
http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/jhuxhorn_googlemail_com-zal6c

For now, no solution, the warning is said to be 'bugged'.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is currently no fix for the issue. The bug has been filed here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65501

Comment: The link goes back to this page