# Gradle deprecation "Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact..." in Android Studio project can be fixed?

Tags: gradle, android-studio, deprecated, android-gradle-plugin

I'd like to learn how to use **Android Studio** at the best, but I still have limited experience especially in building with **Gradle**.

> Executing tasks: [clean]
>
> Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has
>   been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
>   :app:clean UP-TO-DATE
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Even if everything works I would like to avoid using **deprecated** methods;

I state that I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934598/what-does-the-message-relying-on-packaging-to-define-the-extension-of-the-main) and tried to understand the deprecation message but fairly the focus for me now is understanding building APK on Android Studio and how to put hands in a project created by this IDE.

Is it possible to fix-it by changing something (configuration files or artifacts) in the project?

PS: I'm on "Android Studio (preview) 0.4.3 build 133" and in the  project there is two build.gradle:

> 1) **~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyAppProject/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}
```

> 2) **~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyAppProject/build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

and one settings.gradle

> **~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyAppProject/settings.gradle**

```
include ':app'
```

Comment: Can you include the build.gradle file from the module that's giving you this error? I think you only included the one from your top-level project, which has some global boilerplate stuff.

Comment: @Scott Barta thanks to your comment I  realize that I have  more than one **build.gradle**. I edit the question to adapt it to your suggestion.

Comment: I get this is AS 0.5.1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the Android Gradle plugin and not something you're doing wrong; I see it coming up any time you include a dependency in one of your modules even if it's specified correctly. This warning isn't anything to worry about.

I've filed https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65501 about this.

Comment: How to solve this issue is discussed here: http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/jhuxhorn_googlemail_com-zal6c For now, no solution, the warning is said to a bug