# Android studio 0.5.9: 2 annoying Gradle warnings

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I've upgraded to Android Studio 0.5.9 and am always getting these warnings:

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0
```

is there anything I'm supposed to about it? If not, can I disable them?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934598/what-does-the-message-relying-on-packaging-to-define-the-extension-of-the-main and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496956/gradle-deprecation-relying-on-packaging-to-define-the-extension-of-the-main-art, maybe it helped

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Googling on `Gradle incubating feature` results in [this page](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/feature_lifecycle.html):

> C.1.2. Incubating
>
> Features are introduced in the incubating state to allow real world
>   feedback to be incorporated into the feature before it is made public
>   and locked down to provide backwards compatibility. It also gives
>   users who are willing to accept potential future changes early access
>   to the feature so they can put it into use immediately.
>
> A feature in an incubating state may change in future Gradle versions
>   until it is no longer incubating. Changes to incubating features for a
>   Gradle release will be highlighted in the release notes for that
>   release. The incubation period for new features varies depending on
>   the scope, complexity and nature of the feature.
>
> Features in incubation are clearly indicated to be so. In the source
>   code, all methods/properties/classes that are incubating are annotated
>   with Incubating, which is also used to specially mark them in the DSL
>   and API references. If an incubating feature is discussed in this User
>   Guide, it will be explicitly said to be in the incubating state.

---

Searching for `Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0` results in this question as @shayan pourvatan stated:

> [Gradle deprecation "Relying on packaging to define the extension of the main artifact..." in Android Studio project can be fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496956/gradle-deprecation-relying-on-packaging-to-define-the-extension-of-the-main-art)

and [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65501), which says this at the end:

> Based on http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/jhuxhorn_googlemail_com-zal6c a member of the Gradleware team said "There's no way around the warning at the moment, but the warning is bogus."
>
> So there is nothing we can do right now.