# phonegap build fail : Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'

Tags: android, cordova

When trying to build my app

```
phonegap local build android
```

I have this issue :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have no idea of how to resolve this, since this problem is mostly encoutered by people developing their app in java.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. It turned out to be that I had bad (or missed) some icon/splash-screen images (ie: platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi etc) and other images.

You can check that runnning './gradlew --debug clean build' from your platforms/android directory. Search in the log for the ':processDebugResources FAILED' string and close to it the file-name that caused the problem. In my case it was 'año nuevo.png' (the 'ñ' caused the issue)

If that doesn't work, have a look at these other SO-questions, they may help too:

- [ionic build android failure - Execution failed for task processDebugResources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645900/ionic-build-android-failure-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources)
- [Cordova build android error Execution failed for task ':processDebugResources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36258106/cordova-build-android-error-execution-failed-for-task-processdebugresources)
- [Android Studio build failed at "processDebugResources" when using 9-patch images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35030962/android-studio-build-failed-at-processdebugresources-when-using-9-patch-images)

PS: Im using latest phonegap (6.3.0) and latest Android Studio (2.1.2)